# containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier getting nil value

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7, nsfilemanager, nsurl

I am making two iPad app that communicate with one file and fetches all the data from one file. I search and find this "containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier" we can create group and store in that. I have write the code below. In entitlement file i write

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
       <true/>
     <key>com.apple.security.application-groups</key>
     <array>
        <string>$(TeamIdentifierPrefix)com.xxx.catalogapp.Coredata</string>
     </array>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)com.xxx.catalogapp.Coredata</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And in Code i write this

```
NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSURL* storeUrl = [fileManager 
containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"com.xxx.catalogapp.Coredata"];
NSLog(@"%@", storeUrl);
```

But storeUrl I am getting `nil` value.

Comment: The documentation seems to indicate that you would need the teamIdentifier within the string you sue to access the container.  See here in "The application group container directory:" https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html

Answer (score 6):

Xcode6 (currently in beta) enforces the shared folder IDs to start with "group."

Sharing my CoreData store works for me with the following URL with Xcode6/iOS8 both beta.

```
NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSURL* storeUrl = [fileManager containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"group.XXX"];
```

It seems the documentation that stevesliva linked will be obsolete as soon as Xcode6 will be released

Answer (score 2):

Well, I verified it in my own code.  The Team Identifier shows up in the subdirectory of Library/Group Containers, so you do in fact need to include it in your code:

```
NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSURL* storeUrl = [fileManager containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"YOURTEAMID.com.xxxxxxxxxxx.catalogapp.Coredata"];
NSLog(@"%@", storeUrl);
```

What I'm not sure about is whether that's a required name-- it's not very user friendly-- or whether it's something Apple is recommending to make it super-unique.

As mentioned in the comment above, this was figured out starting with Apple's [Application Sandbox Design Guide - Application Group Container Directory:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html)

> These group containers are automatically added into each app’s sandbox container as determined by the existence of these keys, and are stored in ~/Library/Group Containers/, where  is the name of the group. The group name itself must begin with your development team ID, followed by a period.

Comment: This is definitely not the case—shared folder IDs start with "group." and end with the identifier you set up in the iOS Dev portal.

Comment: @BenJackson, either the reference cited in my comment on the question, or you are incorrect.  I updated the answer with a handy pullquote for you.  The answer was perhaps accepted because Hitendra read both the comment and the answer-- the answer was missing info from the comment.

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 11, there is a better way to get shared container URL.

[NSFileProviderManager defaultManager].documentStorageURL

Answer (score -4):

Make sure you're signing both your app and your extension with the same provisioning profile!

Comment: This is not possible since they are required to use different bundle ids

Comment: If you read the question, he is asking about two separate iPad apps and not an extension/app combo.