# Trouble persisting firebase auth on multiplatform app (macOS + iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, macos, firebase-authentication

### Setup 1:

I have a swift app with a single target that runs on both iOS and macOS - `com.teamName.appName`.
I have an app group `group.com.teamName.appName`and a keychain sharing group `com.teamName.appName` for it.
When setting up the authentication, i use

```swift
try Auth.auth().useUserAccessGroup("group.com.teamName.appName")
```

I need this in order to stay signed in in my app extensions, like notifications or share extension.

### Issue:

In this setup without doing anything else, the auth state on iOS persists but macOS requires re-authenticating each time because the above try statement throws `Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17995 "An error occurred when accessing the keychain.`

### Fix attempted:

Now, looking around online i found that providing the team id inside the group name would fix the issue. So basically going from `group.com.teamName.appName` to `teamId.group.com.teamName.appName`.
This behaviour is already done under the hood for keychain groups. Setting the keychain group on the target as `com.teamName.AppName` will actually set it as `$(AppIdentifierPrefix)com.teamName.AppName` if you look in the entitlements.

### Result:

MacOS compiles, runs fine and the authentication persists, but the iOS target no longer compiles with the following error: `Application Group identifiers should start with 'group.'`  **but only when trying to compile on a physical device**

Looking for any guidance on what i am doing wrong and or what i can improve on to have both apps compile, run and persist their authentication state.

Thanks!

Comment: I think the following answer would clarify it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66639271/2715565