# Cannot create an SQL store with a nil URL

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, ios8-today-widget, today-extension

So I am trying to create a today widget extension using the data stored by the parent app.

I am trying to do so by creating a `Persistent Store Coordinator` as you do in parent app and using the URL for the main app database.

However when doing so I get the following error;

> 2016-03-13 12:59:02.155 TodayWidget[10942:1456153] Failed to inherit
>   CoreMedia permissions from 5079: (null) 2016-03-13 12:59:02.336
>   TodayWidget[10942:1456112] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot create an SQL
>   store with a nil URL.'

Here's what I am doing in the Today widget view controller. The `containerPath` is the same as the bundle identifier for the today extension target. The `containerPath?.URLByAppendingPathComponent` sql file name is the same as the parent app core data stack sql file name as well as the the `modelURL` is the same as it is in the parent app.

```
var context: NSManagedObjectContext!

let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
var containerPath = fileManager.containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier("com.company.APPNAME.TodayWidget")

containerPath = containerPath?.URLByAppendingPathComponent("SingleViewCoreData.sqlite")
let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("APPNAME", withExtension: "mom")
let model = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL!)
let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: model!)
    do {
        try coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: containerPath, options: nil)
    } catch {
     print("yellow")
    }

  context = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
  context.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
```

Does anybody know how I can resolve the error ?

PS: I have enabled and created app groups and added the today widget as a target for the core data model and the subclasses.

Comment: Didn't someone already explain the reason, the other time you asked then deleted that question?

Comment: @PetahChristian no, they just said I should investigate the containerPath and also the question wasn't very detailed and the question itself wasn't clear.

Comment: Why didn't you improve the original question?  Nothing has changed regarding the error.  As before, your `containerPath` is still nil.

Comment: `containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier` must be returning nil - have a look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26740404/containerurlforsecurityapplicationgroupidentifier-returns-nil-on-ios-simulator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"com.company.APPNAME.TodayWidget"` looks suspicious. It looks like the bundle ID for your today widget. The argument to `containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier()` should be the string you specified when you set up the `com.apple.security.application-groups` capability.

Comment: Go to your App target > Capabilities > App groups,  to check the string